# Стиль текста в ActionBar'е

Tags: xml, android

Доброго времени суток, возникла необходимость увеличить отступы между строками в виджетах TextView. Для этого я в стилях прописал

```
<style name="BlueTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/BlueActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="TextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.1</item>
</style>

<style name="BlueActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/BlueActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/BlueActionBar.SubtitleTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

После этого в ActionBar'е изменились отступы между строками, но вернуть значение именно в ActionBar'e к 1.0 не удается, делал я это так:

```
<style name="BlueActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.0</item>
</style>

<style name="BlueActionBar.SubtitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.0</item>
</style>
```

Но результата это не принесло. Собственно, вопрос: что прописать в стилях, чтобы для всех TextView, кроме тех, что в ActionBar'е, значение android:lineSpacingMultiplier было 1.1, а для остальных, тех, что в ActionBar'е, значение осталось 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вы используете Support Library. Тогда надо писать без "android:", вот так:

```
<style name="BlueTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/BlueActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Быть может, вот тут ответ найдете https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html